# How to know which component triggerd an p:ajax request

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I have multiple input field with a p:ajax with a listener. They all connect to the same listener. How can I know what component triggerd the listener?

```
<h:inputText id="postalCode" size="20" value="# businessPartner.primaryAddress.postalCode}" 
<p:ajax event="change" listener="#{businessPartner.primaryAddress.retrievePostalCodeCity}"  >
</p:ajax>  
</h:inputText>

<h:inputText id="city" size="60" value="# businessPartner.primaryAddress.city}" 
<p:ajax event="change" listener="#{businessPartner.primaryAddress.retrievePostalCodeCity}"  >
</p:ajax>  
</h:inputText>



public void retrievePostalCodeCity() throws MWSException {
    int country = address.getCountryId();
    String postalCode = address.getPostalCode();
    String city = address.getCity();
}
```

I have this problem because I used to use a4j ajax, but I'm moving the project to fully primefaces and no longer richfaces. The listener to a4j has an AjaxBehaviorEvent event and there I could do event.getComponent().getId()

How can I do the same with prime ajax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`AjaxBehaviorEvent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/event/AjaxBehaviorEvent.html) is not specific to RichFaces. It's specific to JSF2 itself. So you can just keep using it in PrimeFaces.

```
public void retrievePostalCodeCity(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
    UIComponent component = event.getComponent();
    // ...
}
```

As an alternative, or for the case that it's *really* not possible elsewhere, you could always use the new JSF2 [`UIComponent#getCurrentComponent()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#getCurrentComponent%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext%29) method.

```
public void retrievePostalCodeCity() {
    UIComponent component = UIComponent.getCurrentComponent(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance());
    // ...
}
```

By the way, the very same construct should work just fine with JSF2's own `<f:ajax>`. I do not see any reason to use `<p:ajax>` here. It would however be the only way if you were actually using a PrimeFaces component such as `<p:inputText>`.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, the `event="change"` is the default already. You can just omit it.

Comment: I generally prefer p:ajax because of oncomplete if I need to aware of process done.

Comment: That's true, but the OP's particular construct doesn't show that. I explicitly mentioned that in OP's particular construct, the `<f:ajax>` could be used as good.

Comment: I don't want to use the onstart and oncomplete, therefore I use p:ajax. Problem is that if I change my listener to public void retrievePostalCodeCity(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) { . I get an error: javax.faces.FacesException: Target Unreachable, identifier 'businessPartner' resolved to null

Comment: The `<f:ajax>` doesn't have `onstart` and `oncomplete` attributes at all, so your argument makes no sense, so I'll ignore it. Coming back to your concrete problem, this problem is caused elsewhere which isn't visible in the information provided so far. An SSCCE would help.

Comment: I mistyped, I want to use onstart and oncomplete. Therefore I want to use p:ajax in stead of f:ajax. Don't knwo where my mind was when typing the previous comment. Apparently not with my fingers.

Comment: As to my problem: I found out a 'why' it is giving me the error. But I don't have a solution. As it not 100% the same question, Ill ask it in another question: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13561941/target-unreachable-when-ajax-request-when-used-in-uiinclude

Answer (score -2):

It is almost same in primefaces:

```
 <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{businessPartner.primaryAddress.retrievePostalCodeCity}"  />


import javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent;
.....
public void retrievePostalCodeCity(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
...
}
```

If you want to access via **button** component *action/actionListener* tag you can use `ActionEvent` and for any case make sure you set *ajax="true"*:

```
<p:commandLink actionListener="#{businessPartner.primaryAddress.retrievePostalCodeCity}" ajax="true" />

import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;

....

public void retrievePostalCodeCity(ActionEvent event) {
    ...
    }
```

Comment: This answer was already given. Why are you repeating an already given answer? This is a Q&A site, not an ordinary and primitive discussion forum wherein everyone repeats each other upon agreement. If you have an agreement, just express it by voting, not by repeating the answer.

Comment: When I was writing you have already done, but I have updated with additional info. You can keep for additional info, you got vote:)

Comment: I don't need it via commandbutton. I want to trigger it when I edit an inputfield